# NextJs: getServerSideProps is not working with Apollo: fetch failed

Tags: next.js, apollo

I'm trying to generate the page from the server side page on `Next.js`, But I'm having a problem with it, so I have created an `Apollo` instance and I'm importing a `Query` from my queries, and I pass the variable as I do on `useQuery` from apollo on the client, because I don't know another way to do that, also how to handle errors on this?

Here are my `getServerSideProps`:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const slug = context.params.slug;

  const data = await Static.query({
    query: LANDING,
    variables: { slug },
  });

  return {
    props: {
      data: data,
    },
  };
}
```

Here is my query:

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export const CATEGORIES = gql`
  query CategoriesView {
    CategoriesView {
      _id
      Name
      Description
      Icon
    }
  }
`;
```

Here is my Client:

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  HttpLink,
  ApolloLink,
  InMemoryCache,
} from "@apollo/client";

const uri = "http://localhost:3000/api"

const httpLink = new HttpLink({uri});

export const Apollo = new ApolloClient({
  ssr: typeof window === "undefined" ? true : false,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: ApolloLink.from([httpLink]),
});
```

But I get this error: failed to fetch

Here is a screenshot of it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example, working in my case.

```
import { useSubscription, useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { serverSideTranslations } from "next-i18next/serverSideTranslations";

//your query here ; first check if your query works (use your playground)
const QUERY = gql`
    query {
        customers{
            data{
                attributes{
                    firstname
                    lastname
                    location
                    phone
                    createdAt
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;


const Page = () => {
    //apollo function
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(QUERY);

  if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>
  if (error) return <div>Failed to load!</div>

  return (
    <>
      {JSON.stringify(data)}
    </>
  )
};

//can do with staticProps, serverProps, etc. Below just an example - delete if not needed
export async function getStaticProps({ locale }) {
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common"])),
    },
  };
}

export default Page;
```

I am not sure if you can put gql query in `getServerSideProps` because apollo creates some sort of "cache" for your queries.

And check `@apollo/client` library

Comment: Why I'm thinking this is not related?

Comment: I am not sure you can really trigger gql request from getServerSideProps. getServerSideProps runs server-side, fe Vercel uses multi-server hosting.

Comment: So what I can do, I'm using Graph?

Comment: My bad, check this link: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-apollo/pages/ssr.js

Comment: But if you check, https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-apollo/lib/apolloClient.js, resolvers are not being called no where

Comment: I tried that still same error hmm